# Backing up database with missing datafile

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-12c

Is there a way to backup a Oracle 12c database which has a missing datafile?

I dont have backups. Database is running in archive log mode. One of the data files is physically missing from the disk.

But querying dba_data_files, it shows up as a datafile and when I try to backup using RMAN or expdp, it throws an error and fails.

What are the options I have got here?

Oracle12c/RHEL 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `SKIP` options in your backup command.

[image]

For example:

`BACKUP DATABASE SKIP INACCESSIBLE;`

or take the datafile offline, and:

`BACKUP DATABASE SKIP OFFLINE;`

[skipSpec](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RCMRF/rcmsynta006.htm#i1017259)

Comment: Will I be able to make it offline even if the datafile is not physically available in the file system?

Comment: @tesla747 Yes .